# I want to develop browser app but I am getting errors

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-webview

I am new to Android I want to develop a browser app now I am trying to develop it, in this I am getting errors. I tried in another method also on that it's asking on which browser you have to open like that but for me I want to open in my app only.

**WebviewActivity.java**

```
package com.example.admin.fristapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebviewActivity extends Activity {
    WebView webview1;
   // String url = "http://www.google.com";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
        webview1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
      //  webview1.loadUrl(url);

        //MyBrowser my ;

        new Background().execute();


    }

    public class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }




    public class Background extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings)
        {
            search();
            return null;
        }
    }
    public void search()
    {
        webview1.setWebViewClient(new WebviewActivity.MyBrowser());
        String url = "http://www.google.com";
        webview1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview1.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

**logcat**

```
java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread 'AsyncTask #4'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread. (Expected Looper Looper (main, tid 1) {180a245b} called on null, FYI main Looper is Looper (main, tid 1) {180a245b})
                                                                            at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:2290)
```

## Afteredit

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebviewActivity extends Activity {
    WebView webview;
    String url = "http://www.google.com";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

        webview =(WebView )findViewById(R.id.webview1);
                //WebView(WebviewActivity.this);
        webview.loadUrl(url);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                // Do your code when page finished
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi, not required background thread to run the webview UI . It will execute in UI thread

Comment: no after that i want include processing bar thats why i am yousing that

Comment: You should be override  onPageFinished to track your progress for laoding

Comment: ok tried that but its not opening in my app it asking on which browser you want to open it like that

Comment: If it's a new project, I would recommend to use https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are loading a url in `WebView` in `doInBackground()` method. 
You should do on the UI thread.

`loadUrl()` is already doing everything asynchronously. So no need to of `AsyncTask`. Move your code in `onCreate()` method.

If you want to display a loading indicator, you need to use as below :

```
WebView webview = new WebView(MainActivity.this);

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {    
        view.loadUrl(url);    
         return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
           super.onPageFinished(view, url);

           // Do your code when page finished
     }
});

webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` permission added to your manifest file ?

Comment: ya i given that permission also

Comment: what's an error ? Post you updated code in question so i can correct it.

Comment: ya i posted now

Comment: Move `webview.loadUrl(url);` after `webview.setWebViewClient()`

Comment: sorry i am not getting